# How Does Learning Moves Work in Pokemon Quest?

Tags: pokemon-quest

I've been playing pokemon quest recently, and I've been trying to give my starter better moves. it currently has Scratch and Fire Spin, a "close range" and a "long-range" move. I am concerned about replacing scratch because it's strong and I don't wanna get a weaker move, but when I tried to replace the "long-range move", Fire Spin for another Charmander's Fire Punch, in Fire Spin's slot, it gave me another "long-range" move, Ember. however, when I tried to replace Onix's Iron Tail, another "close range" move, using a bunch of random pokemon, I got Flash Cannon, a "long-range" move.  **if I attempt to replace scratch, will I get another "close range" move, or is move replacement done  differently?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Pokemon has a [list of moves](https://www.gamerbraves.com/pokemon-quest-guide-move-tier-list-best-moves-of-every-pokemon-listed/) that it can learn. When you teach a Pokemon a new move, the move is chosen randomly from the Pokemon's corresponding list, with an equal chance for each move provided it does not already know it.

The characteristics of the move, such as being close-range, long-range, or a non-damaging move, do not affect which move is learnt. Charmander has an equal chance of learning Fire Punch by replacing Scratch as by replacing Fire Spin (1/3 chance when Charmander knows two moves).

The only way to affect the chance of learning a move is by evolving the Pokemon. That changes the list of moves that the Pokemon can learn, usually by adding new moves to the list. In the case of Charmander, it has a lower chance of learning Fire Punch after evolution, since there are more moves it can learn as a Charmeleon (1/5 chance when Charmeleon knows two moves) and even more as a Charizard (1/8 chance when Charizard knows two moves).

Comment: so it's completely random whether or not I learn a useful move. yay...